# Is it possible to generate a URL with Checksum outside APEX?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I created an Email sending from PLSQL with URL Link that will be redirected to APEX application once clicked but it is protected by Session State protection.

Can someone help me on how to generate a URL Link with Session from PLSQL Procedure Outside Apex please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `APEX_SESSION.CREATE_SESSION` to generate a session and generate the url using `APEX_UTIL.CREATE_URL` with the correct value for argument p_checksum_type.

Comment: Is this plugin or built in on oracle db? I already tried this but it says CREATE_SESSION must be declared.

Comment: What is the version of apex ? I see you tagged 5.1 - is that really the version ? The procedure APEX_SESSION.CREATE_SESSION was added in 18.1

Comment: Yes version 5.1. Oh I see. Is there any way to do it for 5.1? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.talkapex.com/2012/08/how-to-create-apex-session-in-plsql/) blog can help ? But... I would seriously consider upgrading. Apex 5.1 is over 6 years old, no longer supported an 11 (11 !) releases behind the current version. The longer you wait the harder it will become to upgrade.

Comment: Actually its not my decision hehe its on my superior. BTW thank you for answering my questions. :)